# Does a capacitor discharge itself when the charging voltage becomes 0?

Tags: capacitor

I am charging my capacitor with a binary pulse train (either 1V or 0V). I notice that when the voltage stays at 0V, the capacitor discharges itself.

As shown, the green curve signal is connected to one terminal of the capacitor, and the blue curve signal is the voltages across the capacitor.

[image]

Is this expected? Previously, I thought the voltage will rise when 1V but never fall when 0V. So I am expecting voltage across the capacitor to be a "staircase" waveform.

Comment: How does the circuit look like? Is it a simple RC circuit? If not can you please post it?

Comment: Without diode or anything like that, nothing stops the charge from flowing back to the 0V potential.

Comment: @nav The charging signal (green) is generated by a complex circuit. But it is directly fed into a capacitor's terminal whose the other terminal is grounded. So I think it is a simple RC circuit.

Comment: @JonasWielicki because my input signal, as you can see, is only 1V, adding a diode incurs too much voltage drop, which in turn causes the voltage too small to charge the capacitor. How may I fix it?

Comment: @FarticlePilter Your comments suggest that you have a [specific problem to solve](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why don’t you post that problem instead? (This is fine though if you’re mainly interested in the behaviour of a capacitor right now, and no offense intended)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this expected? Previously, I thought the voltage will rise when 1V
>   but never fall when 0V. So I am expecting voltage across the capacitor
>   to be a "staircase" waveform.

What you are looking to achieve is called an integrator. With an integrator, the output stays where it formerly reached before the input dropped to 0V thus, it kind of latches the amplitude - it has nothing to integrate anymore and the output stays constant until the input rises to some other no-zero value.

Comment: Thank you sir. I followed your advice, using an integrator, in the end.

Answer (score 4):

The discharge is expected. The idea is simple: When the charging voltage is +1, the capacitor tries to reach that value and you see the wave rising. Later, when the charging voltage changes to zero, the capacitor does the same: it tries to reach the value == 0. So you see the wave going down. The easiest way to prevent this is to add a diode in series to the capacitor.

If you wish to see a staircase without a diode, you can try increasing the duty cycle of the charging wave to (roughly) 70% and put a resistance in series to the capacitor. This will get you a rather dirty staircase during the transient phase, but it will soon settle to +1.0V